# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

¿Dónde estoy errando?

```
int (*funcion_c)(void*,void*);

int f_comparador(int* n1, int* n2){
     //Implementación...
}

funcion_c=f_comparador;  //WARNING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En una cosa muy simple: `void *` **no es lo mismo** que `int *`.

Si bien `void *` puede usarse, en la declaración de funciones, para indicar *cualqier tipo de puntero*, esto **no ocurre así** en la declaración de *punteros a funciones*. En estos casos, la coincidencia ha de ser **exacta**.

Tienes varias soluciones:

1. cambia el tipo de tu variable *puntero a función*. Sería lo mas *correcto*:

   ```
   int (*funcion_c)(int*,int*);
   ```
2. Cambia el tipo de tu función ... y su *cuerpo*, claro está:

   ```
   int f_comparador(void* n1, void* n2) { ...
   ```

Hay mas soluciones. Solo te las recomiendo si sabes **muy bien** lo que estás haciendo. Todas ellas se basan en el principio de `aqui mando yo`. Cuando el compilador avisa ...

3. Realiza un moldeado *explícito*:

   ```
   funcion_c = (int(*)(void*,void*))f_comparador;
   ```
4. Usa *algo* intermedio. Las `union` son muy útiles para estas cosas:

   ```
   union {
     int ( *fv )( void *, void * );
     int ( *fi )( int *, int * );
   } paf;

   paf.fi = f_comparador;

   paf.fv( &v1, &v2 );
   ```
5. Déjalo como está. Es un *aviso*, no un *error*. *Dependiendo* de lo que quieras haces, te funcionará ... o no ;-)

**Insisto**: las 3 últimas son para casos *excepcionales*, y has de saber lo que haces. Las funciones trabajan bien con los tipos correctos. Llamar a una función con un argumento inadecuado *a las malas* ... suele producir resultados *curiosos* :-)